# How to append values of an array to an SQL statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, arrays

```
let todo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var stmt = "SELECT * FROM MY_USERS WHERE USER_ID = ?";

connection.query(stmt, todo, function(err, row) {
});

connection.release();
```

I would like to ***`SELECT * FROM MY_USERS WHERE`*** the ***`USER_ID`*** could be any of the values in the array ***`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`***.

Is there a way I could do this without iterating over the array, constructing a new string segment and concatenating it to a final query statement?

Thank you all in advance.

**EDIT**

I cannot tell the exact number of the array elements in advance, so **`SELECT * FROM MY_USERS WHERE USER_ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,?)`** will not do.

Comment: Your title says insert but you'r query has select. Confusing.

Comment: @slon I just edited it to **How to append values of an array to an SQL statement in Javascript**

Comment: You can turn the array to string separated by comma and put into ....USER_ID IN(Comma Separated string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let todo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var stmt = `SELECT * FROM MY_USERS WHERE USER_ID IN (${todo.join(",")})`;
console.log(stmt); // your query
```

You can use template literals like this,In this way you wouldn't have to bother about number of elements in array.See [Array​.prototype​.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

```
let todo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var stmt = `SELECT * FROM MY_USERS WHERE USER_ID IN (${todo.join(",")})`;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM MY_USERS WHERE USER_ID IN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? ,? ,?)
```

Just make sure the number of **`?`** matches the number of elements **`in`** your parameter array

Then finally, use **`todo.length`** to do something like :

```
let todo = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var stmt = "SELECT * FROM MY_USERS WHERE USER_ID IN (";

for (let i = 0; i < todo.length; i++) {
  if (i === 0) {
    stmt += "?";
  } else {
    stmt += ", ?";
  }
}

stmt += ")";

connection.query(stmt, todo, function(err, row) {});

connection.release();
```

Comment: Thank you for the response @aaron, but there is no way to tell the length of the array in advance.

Comment: use todo.length then do something like stmt = 'SELECT * FROM MY_USERS WHERE USER_ID IN ('; for (let i=0; i<todo.length; i++){ if (i === 0) {stmt += '?'} else {stmt += ', ?'} }; stmt += ')'